# Convert div tag to tbody tag in reactjs or pure js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have below code to generate table. Data is comming through `searchkit`

```
                              <Table>
                                <Thead>
                                    <Tr>
                                        <Th>ID</Th>
                                        <Th>PR</Th>
                                        <Th>Order Details</Th>
                                        <Th>Supplier Name</Th>
                                        <Th>Raised On</Th>
                                        <Th>Status</Th>
                                        <Th>PO</Th>
                                    </Tr>
                                </Thead>
                                <Tbody>
                                {<ViewSwitcherHits
                                        hitsPerPage={10}
                                        sourceFilter={["orderId", "pRNumber", "listOrderProductVM", "listOrderCompanyVM", "createdDate", "statusName", "listOrderPOVM"]}
                                        hitComponents={[
                                            { key: "table", title: "Table", itemComponent: OrderDetail, },
                                        ]}
                                        scrollTo="body"
                                        className='divTableBody'
                                    />}
                                    <NoHits
                                        errorComponent={errorComponent}
                                        translations={{
                                            "NoHits.NoResultsFound": "No Records Found.",
                                        }} suggestionsField="title" />   
                                </Tbody>                               
                            </Table>
```

I'm using react-super-responsive-table. `ViewSwitcherHits` is searchkit functionality which is adding `div` tag as parent in dynamic data. So because of `DIV` coming right after `tbody` the table is not showing properly. So I'm thinking to convert that `div` tag to `tbody`. Is this right approach to do or any other solution?

below is html screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's one way of doing it. A maybe cleaner way would be to get the children of what's returned by the search kit component